# Unity3d Android app crashes with NullPointerException at com.unity3d.player.g.a

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, unity-game-engine, runtimeexception

My unity3d android app crashes with with **NullPointerException** at **com.unity3d.player.g.a** on resuming app from background. I am new to unity and could not figure out what might be causing this. I have given the crash log below.

```
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.myapp/com.me.myapp.myActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2067)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1172)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4586)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.unity3d.player.g.a(Unknown Source)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.unity3d.player.g.b(Unknown Source)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.resume(Unknown Source)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.a(Unknown Source)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.init(Unknown Source)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at com.me.myapp.myActivity.onCreate(myActivity.java:50)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4635)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
07-19 12:58:10.271: E/AndroidRuntime(2593):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2031)
```

I have given my activity class below

```
package com.me.myapp;

import com.unity3d.player.*;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class myActivity extends Activity
{
    private UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer;

    // UnityPlayer.init() should be called before attaching the view to a layout. 
    // UnityPlayer.quit() should be the last thing called; it will terminate the process and not return.
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);

        if (mUnityPlayer.getSettings ().getBoolean ("hide_status_bar", true))
            getWindow ().setFlags (WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        int glesMode = mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1);
        boolean trueColor8888 = false;
        mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

        View playerView = mUnityPlayer.getView();
        setContentView(playerView);
        playerView.requestFocus();
    }
    protected void onDestroy ()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        mUnityPlayer.quit();
    }

    // onPause()/onResume() must be sent to UnityPlayer to enable pause and resource recreation on resume.
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        mUnityPlayer.pause();
        if (isFinishing())
            mUnityPlayer.quit();
    }
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        mUnityPlayer.resume();
    }
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mUnityPlayer.configurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus)
    {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        mUnityPlayer.windowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    }

    // Pass any keys not handled by (unfocused) views straight to UnityPlayer
    public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int count, KeyEvent event)
    {
        return mUnityPlayer.onKeyMultiple(keyCode, count, event);
    }
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        return mUnityPlayer.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
    {
        return mUnityPlayer.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

The game crashes in line

> mUnityPlayer.init(glesMode, trueColor8888);

Can anyone help solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: My app crashed on **myActivity** extending **UnityPlayerActivity** instead of **Activity** with following crash report

```
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.myapp/com.me.myapp.myActivity}: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765): Caused by: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:226)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.app.Activity.requestWindowFeature(Activity.java:3264)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at com.me.myapp.myActivity.onCreate(myActivity.java:33)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-06 13:08:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29765):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: what us at `at com.*.**.***.onCreate(***.java:50)`?

Comment: I was just trying to modify my activity and package name. It is **com.company.myapp.MainActivity**

Comment: what I meant what is the code at line 50 on `MainActivity.java`

Comment: `mUnityPlayer.init(mUnityPlayer.getSettings().getInt("gles_mode", 1), false);`

Comment: not sufficient details to tell the reason. You need to show some code!

Comment: @David I have added my activity class to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is problem of your unity version. It crashes on unity 4.1. Try to run it on unity 4.2 or 3.5 and it will run fine.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to extend your activity from UnityPlayerActivity instead of Activity as you are using the UnityPlayer.

Comment: I think you don't need to call `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` because it's already called on `super.onCreate()` from UnityPlayerActivity

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. That is not a solution. No offence but have you even tried out the stuff you are talking about.